# Use of the Validate button in the Codename One Component Inspector Tree

Tags: codenameone

Does the `Validate` button in the Codename One Component Inspector Tree do a check of UI?

I've never seen a message, a log, a dialog or anything else clicking on it. What is the way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it only checks for nested scrollables, the goal is to add additional checks for common pitfalls but this wasn't implemented yet. See: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validate-owner-badges-imageviewer-picker-range.html

Comment: If there aren’t errors of nested scrollables, is it normal that it doesn’t produce any output? It could be nice if it logs or displays something like “it’s all fine”...

Comment: Probably. Because of the limited set of things we test we didn't want to say the UI is "fine" as that might form a sense of confidence that would be unwarranted. I'll add a message though that the validation has finished.